# How I can disable the question if I will save the password for an site (python)

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a problem.When I open Chrome with selenium and then I log in to an account.But in the upper right corner shows up an pop op if I will save the password.So how I can disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code helps to dismiss the Alert

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

timeout = 5
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
alert.dismiss()
```